# C# RichTextBox Re Colouring

Tags: c#

I found the below code in another post [I researched before posting this]

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

BUT this just adds NEW text with color? What im looking for is below

if it was

```
< //Dont colour
```

if it was

```
<? or <?php //Do colour [Red]
```

And update it on textchanged void. So it checks for coding every time the text is changed

I think it's called syntax highlighting but im not 100% sure what its called. Its just so all the coding is another colour?

Im looking for something like below [Coded this myself for a example what i want the system like]

```
ToColor.Add("WHAT TO RECOLOUR", Color.WhateverToColour);
```

then maybe a foreach or something. but my main problem is doing it for existing text for that void not adding new coloured text?

Comment: To reformat parts of a rich text box, set the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties first, then set SelectionColor and other properties accordingly. This can be done on existing text as well. What have you tried in order to make reactive syntax highlighting?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "in order to make reactive syntax highlighting?"

Comment: In order to make syntax highlighting that reacts to changes to the text, ie. reformats on demand, and not just when adding new text at the end.

Comment: If you mean to update it There are multiple voids that can update is as OnTextChanged and OnSizeChanged and if that doesnt work i could code a while loop to check if its longer or a diffrent size..

Comment: Yes, but *what have you tried*? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: With updating the colour of existing text. Not just adding new text with a diffrent colour?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing so far. I'm awaiting help. The code ive tried is in my post.. But thats for adding new code. But i havent tried anything for existing text because i dont know how to

Comment: You have to loop through the relevant changed text and apply formatting on it again. Please note that Stack Overflow is not the place for "please give me the code to do what I want to do". You need to make an effort yourself. So write code that loops through the code, analyzes it, and selects the appropriate formatting for it, then post questions you might have here.